# Eventlistener is fired on whole document

Tags: javascript, event-handling, click

I have an issue in my Javascript code with the eventlistener.
The Eventlistener (click) is firing over the whole document and not only on the specific element.

external file:

```
function $(selector){
    const self = {
        element: document.querySelector(selector),
        on: (event, callback) => {
            document.addEventListener(event, callback)
        }
    }
    return self;
}

function coy(){
    let _this = this;
    
    
    this.Text = (element) => {
        $(element).on('click', function(){
            alert(document.getElementById(element).value);
        });
    }   
}
```

On page

```
<input type="text" id="text"/>
coy.Text('text');
```

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: `document.addEventListener(event` you are putting the event literally on the whole document. If you wanted it only on the specific element call `addEventListener` on the specific dom object or check within the event lister to see which element fired the event.

Answer (score 0):

What a strange question.

1. You are adding the event listener to the `document` on line 5
2. The constructor function doesn't follow naming conventions. Also, why do you want to preserve `this` that doesn't have the `text()` method?
3. The method isn't static, so you have to instantiate `Coy` before you are able to call `text()` on it.
4. You are passing the argument of `"text"` to the `coy.text()` method, but it seems that it's expecting a selector because it uses that argument in a call of the `$` function.
5. You make some sort of weird bootleg jQuery but then right after you define that function, you still decide to use `document.querySelector`

```js
const $ = (selector) => {
    return {
        element: document.querySelector(selector),
        on: function (event, cb) {
            this.element.addEventListener(event, cb);
        },
    };
};

class Coy {
    constructor() {
        this.text = (element) => {
            $(element).on('click', () => alert($(element).element.value));
        };
    }
}

const coy = new Coy();

coy.text('input[type="text"]');
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by point 5? why wouldn't you use `document.querySelector` if you want to emulate jQuery? what would you use instead?

Comment: @Bravo He defined a `$` function which literally does the same thing as `document.querySelector`, then decided to still continue using `document.querySelector` in his `Coy.text()` function (which I assume is unrelated to his pseudo-jQuery implementation)

Comment: I must be reading the wrong question - `document.querySelector` appears exactly once in the question, and it's NOT in `coy.text` - it's exactly where I'd expect it to be if you're trying to make a poor mans jqueery - in the `$` function

Comment: @Bravo Man by `querySelector` I am also referring to the `getElementById`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to say .. he's passing the string `"text"` to both `querySelector` and `getElementById` thinking they will both get the same element - yeah, that's incredibly wrong isn't it

Comment: @Bravo Code like this makes me lose hope for this world

Comment: harsh but true